# get receiving bytes and sending bytes using netsh command in powershell

Tags: powershell

NetAdapter module is not installed. I have to get the traffic flow (receiving Bytes and sender Bytes) like Get-NetAdapterStatistics commmand using netsh command. is it possible? kindly help

i am not an admin to install new modules.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, this is not a great question (you really should attempt to write some code first) but I have some suggestions anyway. You can actually install modules without being an admin, just use:

```
Install-Module <modulename> -Scope CurrentUser
```

And it will go in to the `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` directory under your profile.

However if you want to try to get these values into a PowerShell object without having that cmdlet, you could use the old DOS command `netstat /e` and scrape the text result to turn it in to an object:

```
$NetStat = (& netstat /e) -split '\s+'

$Stats = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Sent = $NetStat[9]
    Received = $NetStat[8]
}

$Stats
```

Returns:

```
Sent      Received  
----      --------  
256063580 1179546715
```